# How does p2p file sharing software connect two peer in the internet behind NAT

Tags: web, p2p, serversocket, bittorrent, torrent

I am new in computer network field and curious about the question below:

I want to know how two devices which are connected to the internet can connect themselves behind the NAT in p2p network through socket programming. I know the concept of port forwarding, but how can software like BitTorrent connect two devices. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: that is a very broad question, do you have a more specific problem that you are facing?

Comment: I mean, how two devices can establish a connection behind NAT in p2p, like bittorrent

Comment: There is no problem that I am facing, just for the knowledge purpose

Comment: then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37367769/1362755

Comment: Thanks this is exactly i wanted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting P2P over NAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367603/connecting-p2p-over-nat)