# How to avoid to have to set port forwarding

Tags: java, sockets, portforwarding

I'm programming a fat client in Java that permits sending files.
So from LAN 1 with public IP (so called pip1), a first fat client (fc1) with local IP (lip1) sends a file to a second fat client (fc2) on LAN 2 (pip2) via WAN.
I use the protocol TCP/IP on port 8081. So it is working only if I port-forward the port 8081 for lip1 on LAN1's router and with the port 8081 for lip2 on LAN2's router...

It is awful: I guess you have understood I'm not good with network stuff. :s
What is your suggestion? I use **java.net.ServerSocket**

Comment: A client can't send data to another client. Somewhere there has to be a server. If that server is behind a NAT device, there has to be port forwarding. This is not a programming problem but a network setup problem.

Comment: Yes, I name my application a fat client because it is installed on each user's environment. But inside it, there is a true client part who uses a socket to send data, and a server part, launched in another thread waiting for incoming data with a ServerSocket.

Comment: Indeed, when you install a software on your computer, it cannot wait for data from outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I guess I didn't research enough on the topic. :s I have found many ideas here:

- it is all about NAT-T, with protocols like UPnP, ICE, PMP or PCP
- https://github.com/offbynull/portmapper
- [Connecting P2P over NAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30367603/connecting-p2p-over-nat)

  And many others with the keywords "P2P, JAVA, NAT". Thanks to [Marquis of Lorme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/marquis-of-lorne) by launching me on the track.